# How to start chroot when connecting via ssh

Tags: ssh, partition

I have a virtual partition, and when the user logs in the machine using **SSH** I want to mount this partition and set **chroot**, and when they log out, **unmount** the partition.

> The partition has stage3 files from linux.

Comment: Just to clarify, should the selected user(s) be placed into a chroot jail on login, or should all users be placed into a chroot jail upon SSHing into the box?

Comment: What's a virtual partition?

Comment: @GraceThompson, when connect by ssh

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, is a virtual HD, like used in VM